# LED reverse voltage and LED supply issue

Tags: led

I am using LED part number 17-215/BHC-AN1P2/3T which has 5 V reverse voltage and 3.3 V forward voltage ratings.

I have two questions:

1. As I am applying only positive voltage to the anode and negative to the cathode, the LED is only forward biased. So is there any need to verify and consider the reverse voltage?
2. As I am working on 3.3 V supply and the LED forward voltage = 3.3 V, will it work normally or do I need to use any specific circuit for this case?

Answer (score 1):

Actually when referring to the LED, following are the answers to your questions:

- Yes, you need to look at the reverse voltage that may be applied to the LED in the off condition. If there would be no possible way of reverse voltage coming up on LED, then you don't need to worry
- Yes, you would have to apply voltages greater than V_forward of LED to supply current and that has to be limited by putting a resistor in series(Essential for limiting the current).

From the datasheet, I could find the Current to be supplied to be 5mA for some brightness. You can calculate the value of resistor based on, (Vcc-V_forward)/5mA.

You can tune the brightness intensity by changing resistor values. But resistor in series is essential for not damaging the LED(if supply is voltage source not current limited source).

Comment: Thanks for your comment and explanation

Answer (score 0):

> As I am applying only positive voltage to anode and negative to the cathode so LED only forward biased, so is there any need to verify and consider the reverse voltage?

What if you place the LED in reverse during production or prototyping? So yes, you should consider the reverse voltage.

> As I am working on 3.3V supply and LED forward voltage = 3.3V so, is it work normally or need to use any specific circuit for this case?

V<sub>F</sub> range of an LED is given for a test current. Even if there's no test current given you should always take a look at V<sub>F</sub>-I<sub>F</sub> graphs:

[image]

As can be seen from the graph above:

- V<sub>F</sub>=3.3V for I<sub>F</sub>=20mA
- V<sub>F</sub>=3.0V for I<sub>F</sub>=10mA

Here's a simple drive circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdUI6B.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Px can be either an output port or simply a voltage source.

Decide a drive current, I<sub>LED</sub>, and see what V<sub>F</sub> is for that current then calculate R<sub>LED</sub> from \$R_{LED}=(3.3-V_F)/I_{LED}\$.

For example, for I<sub>LED</sub>=10mA, required resistor is R<sub>LED</sub>=30R.

Since the main usage of this type of LED is indication, a drive current of 5 to 15mA could be enough IMO.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation